# CSV header row error when using DataLoader

Tags: data-loader, migration

I am working using DataLoader 45.0.0 to migrate our current SF to FSC. When choosing the CSV file in the "Load Inserts" dialog in DataLoader, I am greeted with the full error "CSV Error: Invalid CSV file format. Please select a different file. Error getting header row from the CSV file."

This is the exact file that I have extracted from the originating database using DataLoader. I believe the error has something to do with the encoding/byte order marks on the file. Even when opening in Notepad++ and encoding in UTF-8 (no BOM) or performing the same task using a Python script, I still receive the same error.

Is there a way to find out what exactly DataLoader is looking for in the header row?

Comment: I have issues with comma and semi-comma. Did you try to replace one by other? IF not, I believe you should share a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [thread](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000D39SAAS) with similar problems.

Try the following:

1. Make sure CSV encoding of data loader settings matches your file (make sure both are UTF-8). There are a variety of settings for CSV parsing: see image

[image]

2. If that doesn't work, Try using dataloader.io instead of desktop client. It apparently gives more detail about errors / works better

Comment: Thanks very much Z33dawg. It was a combination of selecting other delimiters, and the top box "Read all CSVs with UTF-8 encoding". Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Check your Dataloader settings and see if you have anything in the "Other Delimiters" input box.

I was loading a csv that contained dashes "-" in field values. I kept getting the error, "CSV Error: Invalid CSV file format." because my settings included an Other Delimiter of "-":

[image]

After I removed the "Other Delimiter" my file loaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

We removed '-' from csv and it worked

Comment: Additional information would make this a better answer. Please [edit] your answer to include more information.